# How to bulk delete all cancelled builds in Team City?

Tags: continuous-integration, teamcity

I would like to clean-up several build configurations that have a lot of cancelled builds (a lot of tests we did when reworking the configurations)

Do you have any ideas if there is a way to do this as part of a bulk action?

I am aware that I can delete a particular build from Actions > Remove, but i would like to this for several builds at the same time.

Thanks,
Otilia

Answer (score 0):

You can change your Clean-up policy : https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD10/Clean-Up